# Why are brew formulas and casks that outdated?

Tags: homebrew, software-update, package-management

Brew packages are often quite old and especially casks do not get updates for years.

I have used Arch Linux before and might be spoiled by Pacman and the Arch User Repository. Its really a different story when using brew in comparison to that.

Comment: Rather than close this as too broad - I think the one answer is nice and general. If you wanted to list half a handful of packages, perhaps there's a reason why they don't update automagically due to how the authors have set up their source tree. Each update costs money to test / integrate server side let alone volunteer hours to do the actual work.

Comment: I'm sure there are outdated formulas, but the ones that I use are updated regularly (assuming the underlying utility is) and there are always a large list of updated formulas. I can't speak to casks because I don't use those as much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Packages and casks get outdated when no-one is taking the time to update them. That work is done by volunteers.

You could be a volunteer.